# How to make a keybind work unconditionally in mpv?

Tags: key-bindings, mpv

The keys `9` and `0` are, by default, volume- and volume+, respectively.
I often use this stats screen to check filenames and such:
[image: The helpful information screen I use]

Unfortunately, if I try to increase the volume too quickly after checking the filename, `0` instead changes the stats page to an unhelpful "Internal performance info" screen that looks like this until quitting mpv:
[image: unhelpful Internal performance info]

How can I remove this behaviour from the `0` key and make it always act as volume+ instead?

Answer (score 0):

## By re- or unbinding all offending (*also script-specific*) key binds.

While the stats script is active, its key bindings override any existing ones, but those can be changed or removed.
You can add the option `key_page_0=key` to `script-opts/stats.conf` in an mpv configuration location such as the following file:

```sh
# ~/.config/mpv/script-opts/stats.conf
key_page_0=5
# to disable instead: key_page_0=
```

<sup>Unlike most configuration, this file is NOT cumulative with itself across locations. (everything from `/etc/mpv/script-opts/stats.conf` is **ignored instead of added to** if you also have `~/.config/mpv/script-opts/stats.conf`)</sup>

Or append `stats-key_page_0=key` to the `script-opts` list,
such as, to unbind:
`mpv --script-opts-append=stats-key_page_0=`
or in an `mpv.conf` file:

```sh
# ~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf
script-opts-append=stats-key_page_0=
# to change instead: script-opts-append=stats-key_page_0=5
```

### In the meantime:

You can revert the page back to "*Show usual stats*" by pressing `1` while shown instead of restarting `mpv`.
From the [mpv manual](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#stats):

> While the stats are visible on screen the following key bindings are
> active, regardless of existing bindings. They allow you to switch
> between *pages* of stats:
>
> ```
> 1   Show usual stats
> 2   Show frame timings (scroll)
> 3   Input cache stats
> 4   Active key bindings (scroll)
> 0   Internal stuff (scroll)
> ```